# Change database when logging in with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am making an application in which the login screen the user can select a company in a selectbox and each company has a different database, at the moment of pressing the login button I want to change database depending Of the company and to log in the user must be in that database. I have been looking for a bit and it is possible to change the database by placing in the model `establish_connection ("otherbase")` but I do not know how to apply it to the whole system and at the beginning of session with devise

Comment: You should have done some research. Checkout the `apartment` gem at https://github.com/influitive/apartment

Comment: "applying it to the whole system" would be problematic if you have multiple users, some of who might not be logged in.

Comment: @maxple But only for registered users, would not be allowed entry if not registered

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is after sign in check in which database the user is, but therefore you need to connect to every database.

What could be a solution is create a database with all users and a field to which database the user belongs to.
Then after the sign in check which database to connect with.